# React js get value from input quantity

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble with an input I'm trying to get the input of quantity then I have a onClick event that execute the function

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="10" value={item.quantity}  className="form-control"/>



 UpdateItem: function(_id) {
                $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/update/' + _id,
          type: 'PUT',
          data:"",
          success: function(result) {
              window.location.reload();
          }
        });
                  }
```

how do i get a new value on input value is al value={item.quantity} is always number that can't be changed?

Comment: need more context to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) to access the DOM node itself, from which we can obtain the value.

http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/QNNRyp?editors=0011

**Component**

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  updateItem() {
    const input = this.refs.myInput;
    console.log(input.value);
  }
   render() {
        return (
          <div >
            <input ref="myInput" type="number" />
            <button onClick={() => this.updateItem()}>Log Value</button>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```